# What matrix has only negative or zero real part for all the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, eigenvalues

Say $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$,

Is it possible to have a constraint on $X$, such that all the eigenvalues has negative or zero real part?

### What I conjecture

The following $X$ has only negative or zero real part:

$X = \frac{A - A^\top}{2} - \textrm{diag}(\gamma_1^2,\ldots,\gamma_m^2)$

for $A$ and $\gamma_i$ defined on the $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question is too general.

Comment: Isn't your conjecture equivalent to "take purely imaginary numbers, shift them to the left, you get numbers with only negative or zero real part"? Observe that the eigenvalues of any skew-symmetric matrix are purely imaginary (or zero).

Comment: @AndreiMF Yes. I realized it can be proved easily.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial must be a Hurwitz polynomial (see Wikipedia) and for this there is an explicit criterion, the Routh-Hurwitz stability criterion (see Wikipedia).